# Dynamic Script Tag Addition is Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

Is Dynamic Script Tag Addition is Asynchronous? Like dynamically including set of JavaScript files from a different domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is asynchronous. Dynamic `<script>` injection always results in the browser loading an external resource via the DOM (e.g. just like stylesheets, images, flash), which must happen asynchronously to avoid browser lockup.

Are you looking at [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) ("JSON with Padding") by any chance? It uses dynamic script tag injection. It's more and more part of discussions about "AJAX", and the fact that it is impossible to do synchronous JSONP (like synchronous `XmlHttpRequest`) is often overlooked.

Comment: No not using JSONP. Is there way to do synchronously, as in cannot invoke a function if it is not loaded.

Comment: @Rakesh: as my answer stated there is *no way* to do synchronous `<script>` injection. There are ways to do synchronous AJAX however. I will try to dig up some questions on the topic already on stackoverflow.

Comment: in Firefox, however, it is behaving synchronous, even if I wanted it to be async.. why ?? In firebug I can see that a later request has returned successfully, but the previous request tht has not returned is not allowing the returned script to execute further.. :(

Comment: I disagree with the statement "Dynamic <script> injection always results in the browser loading an external resource via the DOM ... which must happen asynchronously to avoid browser lockup." Several browsers set the `async` attribute to `true` by default, but you can override it to load scripts synchronously. For example, see the [Firefox manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). See also [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408805/is-the-async-attribute-property-useful-if-a-script-is-dynamically-added-to-the).

Answer (score 0):

> Is Dynamic Script Tag Addition is Asynchronous?

Yes. It is considered asynchronous mostly because of what happens when the script tag is not dynamically inserted.

A fully formed script tag that exists in the DOM will cause blocking behavior, i.e. the page cannot continue loading other HTML until that particular asset is finished loading. Thus, many developers prefer to place their script tags just before the `</body>` tag. In that way, a tag becomes referred to as `synchronous`.

By contrast, if you dynamically inject a script tag, it tends to not exhibit blocking behavior. I say *tends* because as you've seen in other comments, not all browsers do that. The best thing is to wrap that dynamic script code in a `document ready` callback of some kind. Thus, by contrast, it is technically `asynchronous` because other assets can continue to function alongside that asset and its functionality.