# Alert or Console.log not working from dynamically loaded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I use the following function to dynamically load JavaScript:

```
function loadJS(file, c)
{
    var jsEl = document.createElement("script");
    jsEl.type = "application/javascript";
    jsEl.src = file;
    jsEl.async = false;
    document.body.appendChild(jsEl);
    if (c) { jsEl.addEventListener('load', function (e) { c(null, e); }, false); }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsEl);
}
```

Below is one of the functions contained within a dynamically added file:

```
function formelements_SELECT_add(x)
{
    console.log("add");
    alert("add");
    var id = x[1];
    var value = x[2];
    var index = x[3];
    var select = document.getElementById(id);
    var option;
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = value;
    select.add(option, index);
}
```

I know the JavaScript file gets added correctly and the function gets executed because an `option` is added to the `select` element. Why does the `alert` and `console.log` not execute? If I click inspect, then there are no error messages.

EDIT

This is the code I use to call the function:

```
var typeAndElement = x[0][0] + "_" + x[0][1];
start = i + 1;
if (!window[typeAndElement])
{
    loadJS("https://websemantica.org/scripts/" + x[0][0] + "/" + x[0][1] + ".js", continueManipulatingElements(typeAndElement, actions, x, start, total));
    return;
}
else
{
    fn = window[typeAndElement + "_" + x[0][2]];
    if (typeof fn === 'function')
        fn(x);
}
```

I didn't want to include it initially, because I already knew it was working and it will be unclear how it works considering it is using dynamic data.

Also, I have edited the loadJS function:

```
function loadJS(file, c)
{
    var jsEl = document.createElement("script");
    jsEl.type = "text/javascript";
    jsEl.src = file;
    jsEl.async = false;
    if (c) { jsEl.addEventListener('load', function (e) { c(null, e); }, false); }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsEl);
}
```

The problem appears to be solved now.

Comment: not showing where `formelements_SELECT_add()` gets called

Comment: The function name is dynamically generated. I've not included that code because it's not really relevant considering, I've already confirmed the function gets called.

Comment: If that function were being called, you would definitely be seeing that `console.log` and `alert`. If you aren't, that function isn't being called. If you're seeing an option, it's not being added by that function.

Comment: agree with TJ... not conceivable that those 2 lines would be ignored and the remainder would execute

Comment: I've commented out everything, other than the first two lines. An `option` is still added to the `select`. Therefore, it must be a caching problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things jump out:

1. You're appending the script to the page twice, once to `document.body`, and the other to `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`. The second one will *move* the script from the first place to the second. You really only need to do one of those.
2. You're looking the `load` event *after* appending the element. If the script is in cache, you can miss the event. Hook it *before* appending the script to the DOM.
3. You're not doing anything in the quoted code to call the function that's defined by the script you're adding.

---

Other side notes:

- No need to set `type`, the default is JavaScript.
- No need to set `async`, all dynamically-inserted `script` elements are async ([now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413374/157247), it wasn't always true).
- As [Jarosław Wlazło points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413162/157247) `document.alert` isn't a function; just `alert` is all you need. :-)

Comment: I've commented out `document.body.appendChild(jsEl);` and now, the `alert` and `console.log` execute as expected. What do you mean by `hook it before appending the script to the dom`?

Comment: @DanBray: Making sure that the `addEventListener("load", ...` is run *before* you append `jsEl` anywhere.

Comment: Additionally, the type property of the `src` attribute is typically voided. If it's not present it falls back to `text/javascript` and not `application/javascript`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am already doing that. I will edit my answer to show the code that calls the function.

Comment: @DanBray: No need. But yes, once you removed the `document.body.appendChild(jsEl)`, you didn't have that problem anymore, because you're calling `addEventListener` before appending it to `head`. :-)

Comment: I initially, had it as just `alert`, when it didn't work, I tried other things. That was before, I realised there was a caching problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition: `document` has no `alert` method. It belongs to `window`, so you can call it like this `alert('add')`;

Comment: I did. I just later tried other things when it wasn't working.