# Make IE wait for the babel-polyfill will be loaded from the external resource

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I need to load **babel-polyfill** only for IE. Also it's required to make IE wait and do not perform the `console.log('Checkpoint 2');` and code below it (including **IeOnlyPolyfillTest.js**) until **babel-polyfill** will be fully loaded from the external resource.

```
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var isInternetExplorer = userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > 0 || userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > 0;

    if (isInternetExplorer) {
      var htmlDocumentHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var babelPolyfillScript = document.createElement('script');
      babelPolyfillScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      babelPolyfillScript.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.0.0-rc.1/polyfill.min.js';
      console.log('Checkpoint 1');
      htmlDocumentHead.appendChild(babelPolyfillScript);
      console.log('Checkpoint 2');
    }

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/IeOnlyPolyfillTest.js"></script>
</body>
```

And **IeOnlyPolyfillTest.js** part:

```
(function launchApplication() {
  console.log('Checkpoint 3');
  testSymbolFeature();
})();

function testSymbolFeature() {
  let symbolTest = Symbol('foo');
  console.log(`Symbol feature is working! ${symbolTest.toString()}`);
}
```

First, I cannot add `async="false"` attribute:

```
babelPolyfillScript.async = false; // no effect
babelPolyfillScript.async = 'false'; // async="" will be generated
```

I tried following following solution ([original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413374/4818123)):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "script.js";
console.log("a");
document.body.appendChild(script);
console.log("b");
```

In my case, logs order is always right too, however if to reload page some times, we randomly get cases with error and cases without error (by other words, error conditions is unclear, and it occurs case by case):

Bad case:

[image]

Good case:

[image]

So, what we can do to make `console.log('Checkpoint 2');` and all scripts below wait until **babel-polyfill** will be fully loaded?

Comment: load the polyfill FIRST

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I know I need to do it, but how to do it conditionally for IE only?

Comment: polyfills are usually written in a way that they polyfill only those methods etc that need to be polyfilled

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I am sorry, but it is off-top. Let me repeat what we need to do: we need to load babel-polyfill only for Internet Explorer before any other code will be executed.

Comment: oh - got ya ... so, a script tag as a `load` event you can use ... so, `babelPolyfillScript.addEventListener('load', e => console.log('Checkpoint 2'))` won't log `checkpoint 2` until the polyfill has loaded

Comment: @Jaromanda X, O'K, but what about make waiting `IeOnlyPolyfillTest.js` which below `console.log('Checkpoint 2')`? We don't know in advance what will be in `IeOnlyPolyfillTest.js` so cannot refer to anything in `IeOnlyPolyfillTest.js`.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with loading it dynamically ... all your code will have to wait in similar fashion - it's a real pain in the butt supporting IE - but, as I suggested, load the polyfill in a script tag - that way you KNOW it's loaded before any other code will even be parsed, let alone executed - why can't you do that?

Comment: all documentation regarding using babel-polyfill in a browser states that you include it in a script tag (not a dynamically created one) before all other code ... there is no simpler solution

Comment: @JaromandaX, you mean load it like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.0.0-rc.1/polyfill.min.js"></script>`? I can't do it because it's impossible to do it conditionally only for IE. Other modern browsers don't need **babel-polyfill**, so it will be just a burden for other browsers.

Comment: Do the browser detection on the server-side then. Or add all scripts dynamically in the fashion you've provided (which might have other unintended side-effects).

Comment: @connexo, O'K, I'll do. It will be answer. Thanks.

Comment: And btw, depending on the features you're using, Edge will sometimes need polyfills, too.

Comment: @connexo, well, I'll add Edge detection in condition.

Comment: Firefox support for some modern features might be behind a flag (which would have to be manually enabled by the browser user) as well. Make sure to **only** use features supported in all browsers which you don't serve the polyfills - older Safaris, Opera, KHTML, Konqueror, older mobile browser versions etc etc.

Comment: Or consider using `polyfill.io`.

Comment: well written pollyfills pollyfill conditionally - so there is no "burden" for browsers that don't need the pollyfill - except the first time they visit your page they download the polyfill - so that's an extra 29kB ... once ... and since all documentation for using that polyfill directly in a browser states you should put it in a script tag, then that's what you do - alternatively, rewrite every single bit of your code to wait for the polyfill to load before executing - this would be simple with Promises ... except IE needs a polyfill for Promises - catch 22