# React js multi useScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

Hook:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

Use:

```js
useScript("script1.js")
useScript("script2.js")
useScript("script3.js")
```

How I would like to use it:

```js
useScriptMulti("script1.js","script2.js","script3.js")
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: A hand with what? You haven't described a problem...? You have a hook, and you want to write another hook. Give it a try! **If** you get stuck, post a question with your attempt so people can help you with it.

Comment: That said, a couple of observations: 1. There's basically no point in the cleanup callback there, removing the `script` element from the DOM doesn't do anything to the code it loaded. Once you've loaded a script, you can't unload it (in the general case; it's possible to write a script that can fully clean itself up). 2. There's no reason to use `async = true` on a `script` element you're adding dynamically after the main HTML parsing is complete, it has no effect.

Comment: The same thing applies here: https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-script

Comment: Maybe there's some subtlety on the `async` thing I'm missing, though frankly I don't think so. Note that they *don't* remove the script element in the cleanup (presumably because there's no point).

Comment: The removal of the listener because it is done what is it for in this case?

Comment: So the listener isn't fired if the hook is called with a different script during the period it's loading. Frankly, I wouldn't use anything like that `useScript` hook, it's using a hook for something that hooks just aren't meant for IMHO.

Comment: Even if it is out of context, if you have time I can ask you how you would implement such a hook.

Comment: I really just wouldn't use a hook, so trying to shoehorn it into a hook I thought was valid would take more time than I have at the moment I'm afraid. Re `async`, it is irrelevant as I suspected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408805/is-the-async-attribute-property-useful-if-a-script-is-dynamically-added-to-the

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array of urls to hook.

```
const useScripts = urls => {
    useEffect(() => {

        const scripts = urls.map((url) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');

            script.src = url;
            script.async = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            return script;
        };

        return () => {
            srcipts.forEach((script) => document.body.removeChild(script));
        }
    }, [urls]);
};

export default useScript;
```

And then use it for one script `useScripts(["script1.js"])` or for many `useScripts(["script1.js", "script2.js"])`