# Javascript - DOM ready after loading external javascript?

Tags: javascript, external, document-ready

**Is the DOM always ready when my external scripts have finished loading?**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
</head>
```

Inside base.js, I have an object that loads external scripts. It uses the following method to do so:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    scriptElement = document.createElement("script");

scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
scriptElement.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === "complete") onModuleLoaded();
};
scriptElement.onload = onModuleLoaded;
scriptElement.src = "externalScript.js";
head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Now, when all external scripts have been loaded, a callback function is called. My question is: Is this callback function suitable to place the
rest of my javascript code in? This code needs the DOM to be ready.

My scripts also use jQuery. But I don't think I can use

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

because in my tests that fires before my scripts have been loaded. However, I do not know if this will always be the case. If it will, my callback function is suitable for my DOM-manupilating javascript code.

But if it is possible that my scripts can be loaded before the DOM is ready to be manipulated, I need to find another way.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Always include your as well as external js files at the end of the html file .ie before the closing body tag and include user script  file at the last.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) rather than doing your own browser-inconsistency workarounds (`onreadystatechange` vs. `onload`)? Also, IIRC, there are browsers that fire *both*, so you could get two calls to `onModuleLoaded`; if you don't switch to `getScript`, you might want a flag (if you don't already have one).

Comment: I did not know about the $.getScript method,I am very new to jQuery. Although maybe I should have searched better for a jQuery solution. I will next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [jQuery.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/). If you will try to load external js via `getScript` then you can easily do that.

Delay the ready event until a custom plugin has loaded:

```
$.holdReady( true );
$.getScript( "externalScript.js", function() {
  $.holdReady( false );
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I was looking for. I am just starting out with JQuery and did not know the feature.

Comment: Great. Happy to know :)

Comment: `holdReady` is a great way to address this, nice one. Doesn't really answer the question asked ("Is the DOM always ready when my external scripts have finished loading?"), but...

Answer (score 1):

> Is the DOM always ready when my external scripts have finished loading?

<s>Probably, yes.</s> **No.**

Dynamically-added `script` elements [load their scripts asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491677/dynamic-script-tag-addition-is-asynchronous). You're quite correct that you can't use jQuery's `ready` callback because it looks at when the DOM defined by the main HTML is fully loaded, which may well be before your additional scripts have loaded.

<s>I'd be really, really surprised if the main DOM weren't loaded before your `onModuleLoaded` callback was called. So probably, yes, it'll be ready.</s> **Color  me surprised.** I ran the experiment, and guess what? It's possible for the script load and callback to happen before the rest of the page has been processed. *(This is why I test my assumptions.)*

<s>But if you're worried there may be edge cases around it,</s> you could always use `ready` *within* your callback. If jQuery has already fired the `ready` callbacks and you hook another one, jQuery calls it right away.

Comment: Thank you! That is well explained. That is a good thing to know that jQuery still calls the callback, even after the event has been fired. I think the $.holdReady(true) is very descriptive though.

Comment: @MPS: Agreed, `holdReady` is a good way to address your problem.